# Is it profitable to mine any Altcoin in the Cloud? Amazon aws has servers with GPU.

Tags: mining-profitability, altcoin

As title says, I would like to mine in the cloud. Is it profitable? I don't mean bitcoin because the network hash power is too high at the moment. I'd like to mine, for example, Dogecoin in the cloud. Is it possible and profitable? Thanks!

Comment: Possible? Yes. Profitable? Only if you're not the one paying the EC2 bill.

Answer (score 3):

If it were profitable, everyone would be doing it, increasing the difficulty, and making it no longer profitable. Mining is only profitable for you if you have some advantage over other miners.